# How to get the child product ids from a product id in magento 2

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.2.2

How to get the child products id from a product id in magento 2.

I am saving the products with its custom attributes. And it saved successfully.
But

1. I wish to check what type of product i have using a product id.
2. If i have  a simple product save the product as it is. But if it is a configurable product , I wish to get all the child products and need to assign the attributes to the child also.

So My question is How to check whether the product is simple or config ?

**If it is configurable product, How to get its child product Ids?**

Comment: Can You be More specific About getting child products from product @Sri

Answer (score 2):

This will get **all child products (associated simple products) as an array** of a configurable product by object manager.

```
$configProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);

foreach ($_children as $child){
    echo "Here are your child Product Ids ".$child->getID()."\n";
}
echo "count: ".count($_children);
```

> First, we load a configurable product by its product_id by object
>   manager. You can get an array of associated simple products by simply
>   calling getUsedProducts() from objects type instance.

You can also achieve it by creating Data.php class file 
in **app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/Helper**

[For more information click here.](https://webkul.com/blog/get-configurable-associated-products-id-magento2/)

Comment: please do not use objectManager because u can inject class in constructor function.

Comment: Inject this class in contructor  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product and initiate it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
foreach ($_children as $child){
   $childProducts[] = $child;
}
```

> ***$_product has the product object that is loaded by the corresponding ID***